# Automatically shut down OS(X) between specific times

Tags: macos, operating-systems

This might be a question that's out of the scope of this forum, but I'm going to go ahead and ask it anyway.

Lately I'm finding myself browsing the internet at night, making me lose sleep by browsing reddit, etc. To cure myself from these bad browsing habits, and to improve my sleep, I figured I might as well write some code to make it easier for myself.

Is there a way to shut ubuntu/OS down between specific times? It will have to be un-installable before and during the time it takes effect, obviously.

Any hints/tips/solutions are very appreciated!

Comment: OS X or Ubuntu?

Comment: apple.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask for OS X solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS, you can schedule power events (sleep, wake, shut down, restart, boot) in `System Preferences > Energy Saver > Schedule…`.

However, if you have the power to enable it, you have the power to disable it, so it won't save you from your bad habit.